# How to aggregate data in R with mode (most common) value for each row?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set for example,

```
Data <- data.frame(
  groupname = as.factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  someuser = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 10, replace = TRUE))


   groupname someuser
1          a        x
2          b        y
3          a        x
4          a        y
5          c        z
6          b        x
7          b        x
8          c        x
9          c        y
10         c        x
```

How do I aggregate the data so that I get:

```
groupname someuser
a         x
b         x
c         x
```

that is the most common value for each of the groupname.

PS: Given my setup, I have the limitation of using only 2 pakcages - plyr & lubridate

Comment: Why the limitations? is it a homework?

Comment: no, i am automating it through excel and can't program excel to install new packages via R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/2835261) for finding the mode with aggregate.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

aggregate(someuser ~ groupname, Data, Mode)

  groupname someuser
1         a        x
2         b        x
3         c        x
```

Note that in the event of a tie, it will only return the first value.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you - using base R

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  groupname = as.factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  someuser = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 10, replace = TRUE))
Data
   groupname someuser
1          a        x
2          b        x
3          b        z
4          c        y
5          a        z
6          c        y
7          c        z
8          b        z
9          b        y
10         a        z

res <- lapply(split(Data, Data$groupname), function(x) 
  data.frame(groupname=x$groupname[1], someuser=names(sort(table(x$someuser),
             decreasing=TRUE))[1]))

do.call(rbind, res)
  groupname someuser
a         a        z
b         b        z
c         c        y
```

And using `ddply`

```
sort_fn2 <- function(x) {names(sort(table(x$someuser), decreasing=TRUE))[1]}
ddply(Data, .(groupname), .fun=sort_fn2)
  groupname V1
1         a  z
2         b  z
3         c  y
```

Answer (score 1):

Many options. Here one using `table` to compute frequency and `which.max` to select max occurred. within `data.table` framework:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[,list(someuser={
  tt <- table(someuser)
  names(tt)[which.max(tt)]
}),groupname]
```

using `plyr`( nearly the same) :

```
library(plyr)
ddply(Data,.(groupname),summarize,someuser={
  tt <- table(someuser)
  names(tt)[which.max(tt)]
})
```