# Aggregate data in dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I have the following data frame in R

```
DeptNumber  EmployeeTypeId
         1              10
         1              11
         1              11
         2              23
         2              23
         2              30
         2              40
         3              45
         3              46
```

I need to generate another dataframe with a new column `MaxEmployeeType`, which should contain the `EmployeeTypeId` which is repeated the most for a given `DeptNumber`. The output should be as follows

```
DeptNumber  MaxEmployeeType 
         1              11
         2              23
         3              45
```

In case of `departmentNumber=3`, there is a tie, but it is ok to present either of the option. I am not sure what is the optimal way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

A similar question is posted already

[How to aggregate data in R with mode (most common) value for each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684931/how-to-aggregate-data-in-r-with-mode-most-common-value-for-each-row)

but it had a limitation to use only plyr & lubridate. If possible I want a best solution and not limit to these two packages. The question is even down voted possibly due to that it could be homework.

Comment: `aggregate(EmployeeTypeId ~ ., dd, function(x) x[duplicated(x) + (sum(duplicated(x)) == 0)][1])`

Comment: or `aggregate(EmployeeTypeId ~ ., dd, function(x) if (length(y <- x[duplicated(x)])) y else x[1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(DeptNumber, EmployeeTypeId) %>% 
  top_n(1) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Or as per suggested by @jazzuro:

```
count(df, DeptNumber, EmployeeTypeId) %>% slice(which(n == max(n))[1])
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: DeptNumber [3]
#
#  DeptNumber EmployeeTypeId     n
#       (int)          (int) (int)
#1          1             11     2
#2          2             23     2
#3          3             45     1
```

Comment: In a similar way, I had `count(df, DeptNumber, EmployeeTypeId) %>% slice(which(n == max(n))[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
# Mode function
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
# new data-frame
new_df <- data.frame("DeptNumber" = numeric(0), "MaxEmployeeType" = numeric(0))
# distinct departments
depts <- unique(df$DeptNumber)
# calculate mode for every department
for(dept in depts){
    dept_set <- subset(df, DeptNumber == dept)
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, c(dept, Mode(dept_set$EmployeeTypeId)))
}
```

R doesn't have any standard function for calculating Mode. Mode function in the code above is taken from Ken Williams' post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  count(DeptNumber, EmployeeTypeId) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))
```

Comment: And instead of `group_by()` and `tally()` we could use `count()`: `count(df, DeptNumber, EmployeeTypeId) %>% slice(which.max(n))`