# How to group the data in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset in R, which includes IDs and no. of occurrences:

```
ID    Occurrences
1001   A
1001   A
1001   B
1002   C
1002   A
1002   C
```

I would like to get the output as ID (unique) and occurrence (mode), like this:

```
ID     Occurrences
1001   A
1002   C
```

How can I do this in R? I have tried something like "table" but I am not getting a proper answer.

Comment: Why isn't B a part of your answer for 1001? And A part of 1002?   Do you just want the first example of each ID?

Comment: Your question seems to be very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684931/how-to-aggregate-data-in-r-with-mode-most-common-value-for-each-row). Maybe the accepted answer there will help you?

Answer (score 3):

After grouping by 'ID', get the 'mode' of the 'Occurrences'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Occurrences = Mode(Occurrences))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    ID Occurrences
#  <int> <chr>      
#1  1001 A          
#2  1002 C
```

where Mode is

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(Occurrences ~ ID, df1, FUN = Mode)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L
 ), Occurrences = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` answer without any fancy functions or packages

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID) & !duplicated(df$Occurrences),]
> ID Occurrences
1 1001           A
4 1002           C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df1,by=list(df1$ID),FUN=function(x) names(sort(-table(x)))[1] )[,names(df1)]
    ID Occurrences
1 1001           A
2 1002           C
```